# Angular print object with dynamic key

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im have a little problem while making an directive in angular. I got access to the controller and such. My goal is to create a code in my templatefile that looks like this.

Controller

```
$scope.event = {
    name: 'test event',
    time: 'tomorrow',
    place: 'Timmys place'
}
```

Template file

```
<div> event.{{ type }} </div>
```

where the "event" is my controller and the **{{ type }}** is a dynamic value like, name, time, and so on..

Comment: Please describe the actual problem in your question. Just saying "I have a little problem" does not tell us what it is. Also explain what you have tried, what happened and why it did not do what you want.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I'll think of that next time, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div>{{event[type]}}</div>
```

Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/nj1nx7Ge2QahgQ3j5LUd?p=preview